# How to call a assembler function in C

Tags: c, assembly

I have a given assembler function and i should use it in my C code. Is this the correct way? In addition I need sum as the return value. Thanks for the feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void secret(int, int * ) __attribute__((cdecl));

int main(void) {

  int n, sum;
  printf("Give me a number: ");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  secret_func(n, & sum);
  printf("Result: %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declared `secret` but called `secret_func`, so no.  You could more easily declare the return type as `int` instead of passing an output pointer; on x86 for example the return-value register for integer / pointer returns is EAX / RAX in all calling conventions.  Then you'd do `int sum = secret(n);` to tell C to keep that return value in a variable.

Comment: I get a warning. "cdecl" attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
int secret_func(int) __attribute__((cdecl))
i have no idea what i should do.

Comment: IIRC, `cdecl` is already the default calling convention for MinGW.  I think you can make it explicit with `__attribute__((ms_abi))` (as opposed to `sysv_abi`).  I think MinGW GCC probably supports some of stdcall, fastcall, and vectorcall for non-default calling conventions.  If you have any other specific concerns, put them in your question!

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?  Which compiler and linker do you use?  How is your assembly function written and linked into the program?

Comment: So to extend what @fuz is asking: each C compiler has a specific calling sequence that I believe is defined by the compiler.  Parameters are pushed onto the stack, sometime left to right, sometimes right to left.  Do you know for a fact that your assembler routine conforms to the expectations of your specific C compiler?

Comment: @thenewC If you don't answer any follow-up questions, it's unlikely that you are going to receive help.  Please make sure you do!